# Loop Query Parameter Postman

Tags: for-loop, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

im trying to test API using loop query parameter tools but the issue is that the query paramas is getting only the last value of "mark", what i need is to run and test every mark and render it into url,
here my Pre-request Script [image]

and here is the result :

[image]

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what your end goal is. Can you describe the input and output expected. You are looping over a collection of car brands (marks). What do you want to have in the end? Also, you deleted the URL from the postman screenshot but it's on the console log, so you might want to delete that, as the API is public.

Comment: hi @bitoiu , my goal is to test all the brands by entering the brand name in the Query params, here in the pre request script i used for loop to set every car name in the url of GET request,but the issue here as you see the scrpit set only the last brand name "MINI". thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to do this but I got it working by using two requests. The first to get the data, the second as the iteration request. You can see the full workflow working [on this folder I've created for you](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/folder/19391207-54e51f8e-8f86-46eb-8a91-dbededf0f1c9). To test it yourself, just fork the collection and **run the whole folder** on one of your workspaces.

[image]

At a high level this is what you do:

1. Create a folder so you can run these requests as a "flow".
2. Create one request that gets all "marks", store "marks"
3. Create another request that:

- 3.1 While there are marks, remove one mark
- 3.2 Add `mark` as a query param
- 3.3 Save the remaining marks, if none left exit.
- 3.4 Call the same request again

**Code for the first request on `Tests`:**

```js
const responseDate = pm.response.json()
const marks = responseDate.marks.map(x => x.name)

console.log("Obtained a list of brands:", marks)
console.log("Saving brands into marks collection variable")
pm.collectionVariables.set("marks", marks)
postman.setNextRequest("Brand detail");
```

**Code on second request `pre-request script`:**

```js
let marks = pm.collectionVariables.get("marks")
const currentMark = marks.shift()
pm.request.addQueryParams(`marque=${currentMark}`);

if (marks.length > 0) {
    pm.collectionVariables.set("marks", marks)
    postman.setNextRequest("Brand detail");
} else
{
    // Redundant
    postman.setNextRequest(null)
}
```

You can see on the first one I used your real URL, on the second one I couldn't authenticate so I used the Postman Echo API just to be able to send the request.

*NOTE: You have to run the whole folder to chain the requests, otherwise `postman.setNextRequest()` won't work.*

Comment: thank you for helping i really appreciate it , but my goal is to run and test the api directly and  i did it

Comment: What is different from this and your final solution then?

Comment: good morning @bitoiu the difference is here "            pm.collectionVariables.unset("brandnames");" , by this command im reinitializing the mark name in every set

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the problem, here's the new script:

```js
let brandnames = pm.collectionVariables.get("brandnames");
if(!brandnames || brandnames.length == 0) {
    pm.sendRequest("http://cms.ioit.tn/api/cms/home/1", function (err, response) {
        marks = response.json().marks;
        const markname = marks.map(x => x.name);
        let currentbrandname = markname.shift();
        pm.collectionVariables.set("brandname", currentbrandname);
        pm.collectionVariables.set("brandnames", markname);
    });
}
else {
    let currentbrandname = brandnames.shift();
    pm.collectionVariables.set("brandname", currentbrandname);
    pm.collectionVariables.set("brandnames",brandnames);
}
if(brandnames==undefined){
    pm.collectionVariables.unset("brandnames");
}
```